# Using handleChange function for several inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My desire is that the `handleChange` function should only affect the input value that you change. If i change the 'firstName' input i wish that only that state gets updated and same goes for the second input-field, 'lastName'. Suggestions on how this can be done are much appreciated.

**StateObject**

```
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        firstName :"",
        lastName: "",
    });
```

**Input**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" onChange={handleChange}/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Lastname"  onChange={handleChange}/>
```

**handleChange() function**

```
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setUser({...user, firstName:event.target.value})
     }
```

Comment: do you need a `handleChange` function that can be used for all the inputs?

Comment: Yes, currently i've solved this by having a two `handleChange`, one for each input. I wish to have one function that works for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const makeHandleChange = key => event => {
  setUser({...user, [key]: event.target.value});
};

<input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" onChange={makeHandleChange('firstName')}/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Lastname"  onChange={makeHandleChange('lastName')}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is some rough code as I'm not in a position to test it, but the theory should be the same, might need tweaking, you can use a property accessor to update your object. Just tweak the HTML slightly.

**Input**

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" name="firstName" onChange={handleChange}/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Lastname" name="lastName"  onChange={handleChange}/>
```

**handleChange() function**

```js
   const handleChange = (event) => {

        setUser({...user, [event.target.getAttribute('name')]:event.target.value})
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your input and add another attribute of `name`, then access the `name` property of the event and pass that as the property name to the `setUser(...)` function.

**Input**:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" name="firstName" onChange={handleChange}/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Lastname" name="lastName" onChange={handleChange}/>
```

**handleChange() function**

```
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setUser({...user, [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do what you're expecting - add name attribute to your input that matches with your state object that manages the values.

```
const MyForm = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        firstName :"",
        lastName: "",
    });
    const handleChange = (event) => {
      setUser({ ...user, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
    }
    return (
     <form>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Firstname" onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Lastname"  onChange={handleChange}/>
     </form>

    )
}
```

Hope this is helpful :)